# How to deploy two git repositories on same AWS instance with codeDeploy service?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, autodeploy, github-services

I have to deploy two github repositories on AWS.For this, I am using "GitHub Auto-Deployment" service. (deployment service is working fine)

The problem is when the code from one repository deploys on Server the code from other gets automatically removed and vice versa. Please help me to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem? If yes then please update your answer here.